# How to make a props that support three types of different function in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following props interface that should technically support 3 different types of functions all over the app. The current issue is with the last function – for some reason, it is not working and showing the following errors.
The function asks to add parentheses, but even if I do that, I still get an error.

```js
// In Parent component 
  const handleSwitch = () => {
    if (!checked) {
      setLocalGender('male');
    } else {
      setLocalGender('female');
    }
    setChecked(!checked);
  };

<ReusableComponent disabled={false} name='preference' bool={checked} onChangeFn={handleSwitch} />


// Reusable component
interface Props {
disabled: boolean;
name: string;
bool: boolean;
onChangeFn: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => Promise<void> | (() => Promise<void>) | (() => void)
}

<Switch name={name} disabled={disabled} checked={bool} onChange={onChangeFn} />
```

> Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '(e: ChangeEvent) => Promise | (() => Promise) | (() => void)'.
> Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Promise | (() => Promise) | (() => void)'.ts(2322)
>
> The expected type comes from property 'onChangeFn' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'
> (property) Props.onChangeFn: (e: React.ChangeEvent) => Promise | (() => Promise) | (() => void)

Answer (score 2):

Your function type definition is:

```js
(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => Promise<void> | (() => Promise<void>) | (() => void)
```

So it can either return `Promise<void>` or two different types of function.

However, you are trying to pass in a function that just returns `void`. This is distinct from returning `Promise<void>`. If it should be allowed, then you need to add `void` to your union:

```js
(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => Promise<void> | void | (() => Promise<void>) | (() => void)
```

Comment: works like butter on a ribeye.

Comment: but where is the ()=> void going then still don't make sense to me, is it a function model or function return ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question in that comment, sorry. The union type in that definition you've used, after the first `=>`, is all the types that your function can return. Because `() => void` is one of those types, that means your function can return a function with a `void` return type. Does that help?

Comment: e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> is in this case optional as an argument ? sicne  => Promise<void> | void

Comment: @Richardson replace **(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => Promise<void> | (() => Promise<void>) | (() => void)** with **onChangeFn: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => Promise<void> | void;**

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any issues with your typescript declaration BUT IT'S NOT CORRECT because you are using unnecessary typing **(() => Promise) | (() => void)**:

```
import { FormControlLabel, FormGroup, Switch } from "@material-ui/core";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

interface IReusableComponentProps {
  disabled: boolean;
  name: string;
  label: string;
  bool: boolean;
  // Change
  // onChangeFn:
  //   | ((e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => Promise<void>)
  //   | (() => Promise<void>)
  //   | (() => void);
  // To
  onChangeFn: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => Promise<void> | void;

}

class ReusableComponent extends React.Component<IReusableComponentProps, any> {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <FormGroup>
          <FormControlLabel
            control={
              <Switch
                name={this.props.name}
                disabled={this.props.disabled}
                checked={this.props.bool}
                onChange={this.props.onChangeFn}
              />
            }
            label={this.props.label}
          />
        </FormGroup>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default function App() {
  const [bool, setBool] = useState(true);
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(true);
  const [localGender, setLocalGender] = useState<"male" | "female">("male");

  // In Parent component
  const handleSwitch = () => {
    if (!checked) {
      setLocalGender("male");
    } else {
      setLocalGender("female");
    }
    setChecked(!checked);
    setBool(!bool);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReusableComponent
        name="gender"
        disabled={false}
        bool={bool}
        onChangeFn={handleSwitch}
        label={localGender}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

you can check it in sandbox :

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-mui-switch-forked-rxks2z?file=/src/App.tsx:0-1513

[image]

try to re-open your editor/project or check type of the ReusableComponent props